# Uncaught typeError: cannot read property closest of null in Materialize stepper.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, materialize

I am working with `Materialize` css and using `Materialize` stepper but it is showing

`uncaught typeError: cannot read 'closest' of null`

**with** `Django` but **without** `Django` its working fine.

Does anyone have any idea about that?